# An illegal reflective access operation has occurred, while accessing HBase from Scala

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hbase

Getting error on Hbase Scala integration what could have been wrong? This code compiles well and Hbase shell shows proper collections and allows CRUD operations. Hbase installation is on ext4 fs on the laptop.

**Code-**

```
//CHECK ishassan/build.sbt as well
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{CellUtil, HBaseConfiguration, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object ScalaHBaseExample extends App{

  def printRow(result : Result) = {
    val cells = result.rawCells();
    print( Bytes.toString(result.getRow) + " : " )
    for(cell <- cells){
      val col_name = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell))
      val col_value = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell))
      print("(%s,%s) ".format(col_name, col_value))
    }
    println()
  }

  val conf : Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  /*
  From http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/zookeeper.html
  A distributed Apache HBase (TM) installation depends on a running ZooKeeper cluster. All participating nodes and clients
  need to be able to access the running ZooKeeper ensemble. Apache HBase by default manages a ZooKeeper "cluster" for you.
  It will start and stop the ZooKeeper ensemble as part of the HBase start/stop process. You can also manage the ZooKeeper
  ensemble independent of HBase and just point HBase at the cluster it should use. To toggle HBase management of ZooKeeper,
  use the HBASE_MANAGES_ZK variable in conf/hbase-env.sh. This variable, which defaults to true, tells HBase whether to
  start/stop the ZooKeeper ensemble servers as part of HBase start/stop.
  */
  val ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM = "localhost"// "WRITE THE ZOOKEEPER CLUSTER THAT HBASE SHOULD USE"
  conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM);

  val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
  val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf( Bytes.toBytes("emostafa:test_table") ) )

  // Put example
  var put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"))
  put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("d"), Bytes.toBytes("test_column_name"), Bytes.toBytes("test_value"))
  put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("d"), Bytes.toBytes("test_column_name2"), Bytes.toBytes("test_value2"))
  table.put(put)

  // Get example
  println("Get Example:")
  var get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("row1"))
  var result = table.get(get)
  printRow(result)

  //Scan example
  println("\nScan Example:")
  var scan = table.getScanner(new Scan())
  scan.asScala.foreach(result => {
    printRow(result)
  })

  table.close()
  connection.close()
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "HBaseT1"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

resolvers ++= Seq(

  "Hadoop Releases" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/"

)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "15.0",

  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0",

  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapred" % "0.22.0",

  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.0.0",

  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.0.0"

)

dependencyOverrides += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "15.0"
```

**Error on "sbt run"**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/tmp/sbt_d34dd099/target/daff8e34/07497e8b/hadoop-auth-2.6.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[error] (run-main-0) java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.delayedEndpoint$ScalaHBaseExample$1(scala.scala:34)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$delayedInit$body.apply(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
[error]     at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.main(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample.main(scala.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.delayedEndpoint$ScalaHBaseExample$1(scala.scala:34)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$delayedInit$body.apply(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
[error]     at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.main(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample.main(scala.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Constructor threw an exception for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:54)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:34)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:64)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:48)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:625)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.delayedEndpoint$ScalaHBaseExample$1(scala.scala:34)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$delayedInit$body.apply(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
[error]     at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.main(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample.main(scala.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:46)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:34)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:64)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:48)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:625)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.delayedEndpoint$ScalaHBaseExample$1(scala.scala:34)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$delayedInit$body.apply(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
[error]     at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.main(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample.main(scala.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.<init>(IPCUtil.java:70)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.<init>(AbstractRpcClient.java:91)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.<init>(RpcClientImpl.java:1067)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.<init>(RpcClientImpl.java:1093)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:46)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:34)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:64)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:48)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:625)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.delayedEndpoint$ScalaHBaseExample$1(scala.scala:34)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$delayedInit$body.apply(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
[error]     at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.main(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample.main(scala.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected version format: 14.0.1
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ClassSize.<clinit>(ClassSize.java:119)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.<init>(IPCUtil.java:70)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.<init>(AbstractRpcClient.java:91)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.<init>(RpcClientImpl.java:1067)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.<init>(RpcClientImpl.java:1093)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:46)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:34)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:64)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:48)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:625)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.delayedEndpoint$ScalaHBaseExample$1(scala.scala:34)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$delayedInit$body.apply(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
[error]     at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample$.main(scala.scala:8)
[error]     at ScalaHBaseExample.main(scala.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 16-Jul-2020, 6:56:40 pm
```

Comment: The stacktrace says: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected version format: 14.0.1`. Uncompatible java version?

Answer (score 0):

jhamon comment was right, need to compile with -

sbt compile -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/

and run with

sbt run -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/

earlier it was taking "java-1.14.0-openjdk-amd64" and it not seems to be ok with HBase lib.